# Insert elements in a BST

Tags: racket

I get an error with this code, where i try insert elements of a list into a BST.

The error is tree-value: expects a tree, given 4 but i have no clue why this happens.

```
(define-struct tree (left right value))
(define example (make-tree
             (make-tree empty empty 3)
              (make-tree
               (make-tree 4 empty 7)
               (make-tree empty empty 10) 8)5))
(define app (list 1 2 3 4 6 11 12 13))

(define (insert tree val)
(cond [(empty? tree) (make-tree empty empty val)]
    [(= val (tree-value tree)) tree]
    [(< val (tree-value tree))
     (make-tree (insert (tree-left tree) val) (tree-right tree) (tree-value tree))]
    [(> val (tree-value tree))
     (make-tree  (tree-left tree) (insert (tree-right tree) val) (tree-value tree))]))

(define (insert-list tree lst)
(cond [(empty? lst) tree]
    [else (insert-list (insert tree (first lst)) (rest lst))]))

> (insert-list example app)
tree-value: expects a tree, given 4
>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about what defines a tree. In your example a tree is one of

What defines a tree.

My interpretation of your code is that a tree is defined as follows:

```
A tree is one of:
 | empty
 | (make-tree tree tree number)
```

If that is the definition you mean, you are not creating a valid tree. Look at the definition of example: `(make-tree 4 empty 7)` is not valid. You can fix that by changing the definition of example:

```
(define example (make-tree
  (make-tree empty empty 3)
    (make-tree
       (make-tree empty empty 7)
       (make-tree empty empty 10) 8) 5))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `example` tree was incorrectly built - a tree was expected, but a number was passed in the node with value `4`. Also, a value of `4` there doesn't satisfy the order property of a BST (`4` is less than `5`, yet you located it to its right). We should change it to a valid value, say - `6`. Please use this tree instead:

```
(define example
  (make-tree
   (make-tree empty empty 3)
   (make-tree
    (make-tree (make-tree empty empty 6) empty 7)
    (make-tree empty empty 10)
    8)
   5))
```

Comment: Shouldn't `4` be to the left of `5` in the BST?

Comment: @AlexanderMaru Good call, I hadn't noticed that the tree is invalid. I adjusted my answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use DrRacket's stepper to help you understand this problem. Put the code above (along with the `(insert-list example app)` call) into the definitions window, make sure the language level is set to Beginner, and then click on the `Step` button. You can use the menu to jump to the last step of the failed evaluation, where you'll see a call to `tree-value` with 4. How did that happen? Use the step backward button to see the previous step, etc.